# Criação Banco relacionado

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, modelo-relacional

Estou com uma duvida se estou fazendo certo ou não a criação desse banco. Poderiam ajudar se o caminho está certo ou errado. Por enquanto só coloquei id nas tabelas.

Turma

```
Turma | Turmaid
    A  1
    B  2
    C  3
    D  4
```

Municipio

```
   Municipio | municipioid
   municipioA  1
   municipioB  2
   municipioC  3
   municipioD  4
```

Professor

```
Professor | turmaid | municipioid 
  José      3            1
  Maria     2            2
  Allna     4            3
```

Aluno

```
 Nome | turmaid | municipioid | ano_ensino
 Joao      1            1         1º
 Cezar     2            2         7º
 Thiago    2            3         5º
```

Estou com duvida porque um aluno pode ter vários professores ou apenas um, assim como o professor terá vários alunos.
Preciso que em um momento o professor liste seus alunos.
E que no admin eu saiba quais professores aquele aluno tem.

Seria assim? [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Isso se chama relacionamento n:n, ou na verdade, um professor pode ter 0:n alunos, assim como um aluno pode ter 0:n professores, no inicio do semestre, quando os alunos ainda nao foram alocados em salas, por exemplo

Comment: Você devera criar uma tabela auxiliar, `aluno_professor`, onde ira armazenar o `id_aluno` como `fk`, o `id_professor` também como `fk`, e `id_aluno_professor` sendo a `pk`.

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio comecei até a fazer isso mas achei que estava errado ai parei.

Comment: Não, é isso mesmo, dentro da tabela `aluno_professor` você também pode ter outros atributos, como `id_sala`, `id_turma`, e etc... ai varia do escopo do seu problema

Comment: Mas ambos estão relacionados pela _id_ da turma, qual é o problema ?

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio seria como coloquei na pergunta?

Comment: ultima duvida rsrsr @MarceloBonifazio quando vou popular as tabelas precisarei popular no mesmo momento essa professor_relacao_aluno correto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relacionamento entre **entidades** é o tipo de ocorrência existente entre **entidades**.

**Tipos de relacionamento:**

Existem três tipos de relacionamento entre entidades:

*um-para-um*

*um-para-muitos*

*muitos-para-muitos*

No seu caso se aplica o relacionamento muitos para muitos N:N.

Vc pode definir a relação da seguinte maneira:
[image: Cardinalidade N:N]

**Cardinalidade**

A cardinalidade é um conceito importante para ajudar a definir o relacionamento, ela define o número de ocorrências em um relacionamento.Para determinar a cardinalidade, deve-se fazer a pergunta relativa ao relacionamento em ambas as direções.

Um professor possui quantos alunos?

- no mínimo 1 e no máximo N.

Um aluno está alocado em quantas turmas?

- no mínimo em 1 e no máximo em 1

Somando-se as cardinalidades, definimos o resultado final do relacionamento, ou seja, 1:N

[Mais informações aqui.](http://www.luis.blog.br/relacionamento-entre-entidades-tipos-e-cardinalidade.aspx)

Comment: seria como coloquei na pergunta?

Comment: Isso msm, vc pode criar uma tabela auxiliar para fazer as relações entre professor e alunos, assim vc pode ver quais professores possui determinados alunos e quais alunos possui determinado professores.